# Because of htaccess-rules include header with css and javascript breaks

Tags: php

I have the following structure on my php project:

```
- classes
    - model.php
- views
    - header.php
    - footer.php
    - user.php
- resources
    - css
        - stylesheet.css
    - js
        - my_javascript.js
- index.php
- controller.php
```

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?resources/(.*)$ resources/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9/]*)$ index.php?page=$1&query=$2 [L]
```

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <!-- Styles -->
       <link href="resources/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>
```

The problem, as many others have mentioned on stackoverflow before (but whose solutions have not worked for me), is that Im currently redirecting all pages through index.php and therefore even my resources files, such as stylesheet.css.

**1:** When I ask for `mydomain/user` I get the correct resources loaded with right css (`mydomain/resources/css/stylesheet.css`)

**2:** But as Im trying to make the app RESTful, I have a page such as `mydomain/user/4` and when I make a request such as this my css suddently doesn´t load. Looking at the http request its looking for (`mydomain/user/resources/css/stylesheet.css`)

I have tried to solve it by including `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. It does not work, and does not seem to be a "nice" solution. Thanks for your help. And yes I am a newbie at php!

Comment: you need rewrite conditions in your htaccess file. Or use a ROUTER script like any sane PHP developer.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]` Exlude pretty standard asset files.

Comment: Thanks, but no, the condition does not work, good idea though...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are masking the URL and the actual scripts runs on a different folder structure than what is found in the URL, you have to provide full path to the CSS, images, Javascripts etc you refer in your program.

You can change your code to following

```
<link href="http://www.yourdomainname.com/resources/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Or use relative path to the files

```
<link href="/resources/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Since we are using `/` at the starting of file path, server will look for the file from the root working directory of the website.

Along with this you should add conditions in your htaccess file like below

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(resources|img|anyother folders that you want to ignore|anyother folders that you want to ignore|...)
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9/]*)$ index.php?page=$1&query=$2 [L]
```

I hope you will not need `RewriteRule ^/?resources/(.*)$ resources/$1 [L]` in the htaccess after making these alteration

Comment: Thank you, im going to work, but as soon as I come home, I will try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since the changes in htaccess did not work i made the header load an absolute path instead like this

```
$http_host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$file_path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$info = pathinfo($file_path);
$root_path = "http://" . $http_host . $info['dirname']; 
$path = $root_path . "/resources/css/stylesheet.css";
```

I hope this helps someone else with the same problem...